# How to make object from .serialize() string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a serialized form:

```
formObj = $("#form_add").serialize();
```

Then I created wrapped object with two objects (one is object, the second is string formObj):

```
var json = {};
var wrapperObj = {json: json, form: formObj};
```

After all I pass this object to `data` parameter:

```
data: JSON.stringify(wrapperObj)
```

How to build object from serialized string `formObj` in the following line?

```
var wrapperObj = {json: json, form: formObj};
```

Comment: Must you send in json format? If endpoint accepts form encoded data can just send `data:formObj`

Comment: Yes, I need to send JSON

Comment: One object is form data another is object in JS

Comment: serialize does not return an object...it returns a form endcoded string. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/8407771#8407771

Comment: Why it is so hard to do?  Can I make this using native JS?

Comment: It's not hard. Copy the code in answer in link above...and stringify the result. Much simpler if endpoint uses form encoding...even if it returns json

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks